# Understanding named arguments in OCaml and their scope

Tags: ocaml

I'm reading OCaml source code and I'm getting confused about named arguments:

```
 let verify_transport_checksum ~proto ~ipv4_header ~transport_packet =
    (* note: it's not necessary to ensure padding to integral number of 16-bit fields here; ones_complement_list does this for us *)
    let check ~proto ipv4_header len =
      try
        let ph = Marshal.pseudoheader ~src:ipv4_header.src ~dst:ipv4_header.dst ~proto len in
        let calculated_checksum = Tcpip_checksum.ones_complement_list [ph ; transport_packet] in
        0 = compare 0x0000 calculated_checksum
      with
      | Invalid_argument _ -> false
    in
    match proto with
    | `TCP -> (* checksum isn't optional in tcp, but pkt must be long enough *)
      check ipv4_header ~proto (Cstruct.len transport_packet)
    | `UDP ->
      match Udp_wire.get_udp_checksum transport_packet with
      | n when (=) 0 @@ compare n 0x0000 -> true (* no checksum supplied, so the check trivially passes *)
      | _ ->
        check ipv4_header ~proto (Cstruct.len transport_packet)
```

I see that `verify_transport_checksum` is a function that has these 3 names arguments: `~proto ~ipv4_header ~transport_packet`. Then, in the inside, it does `let check ~proto ipv4_header len =`. This is a new `~proto`?

Then it does

```
let ph = Marshal.pseudoheader ~src:ipv4_header.src ~dst:ipv4_header.dst ~proto len in
```

what is this `~proto`? Is it a named argument of `Marshal.pseudoheader`? If so, why it has no value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is doing `label-punning`: It takes some variable-binding from before, and passes it on to another function as a labeled argument of the same name and same value.

```ml
let someArg = "something";;
someFun ~someArg;;
(* is shorthand notation for *)
someFun ~someArg:someArg;;
```

- `verify_transport_checksum` has the labelled argument `~proto`.
- It's used in the pattern matching below, to match against it, and to pass to the `check`.
- The `~proto` in the `check`-definition has the same name as before, so it can be passed through. However, it shadowes the previous binding of `~proto`. If one called it (in the pattern matching below) like `check ~proto:"something else here"`, it would have a different value. In your case, because it gets punned, it has the very same value as before.
- Same thing happens on the `Marshal.pseudoheader`-call, the `~proto` from `check` gets passed through.